# jabber.net not working for vb.net

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to use jabber.net for web application 
i know this is for desktop application as given in below given link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34300/Google-Chat-Desktop-Application-using-Jabber-Net

but i found a post on stack overflow related to this and it say that one dude has implemented it with web application

[Web Chat Application - ASP.NET/Jabber/Ajax/WCF/Comet/ReverseAjax - Issues Faced - Seeking Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226688/web-chat-application-asp-net-jabber-ajax-wcf-comet-reverseajax-issues-faced)

actually the code project code was written in c#

```
using System;    
using System.Collections;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Text;    
using jabber.client;    
using System.Threading;    
using jabber.protocol.iq;    
using jabber;    
using Google.GData.Contacts;    
using Google.GData.Extensions;    
using jabber.protocol;

namespace WebApplication1    
{    
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page    
    {    
        static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);    
        private jabber.client.JabberClient jabberClient1=new jabber.client.JabberClient();    

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jabberClient1.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(jabberClient1_OnMessage);
            jabberClient1.OnDisconnect += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jabberClient1_OnDisconnect);
            jabberClient1.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(jabberClient1_OnError);
            jabberClient1.OnAuthError += new jabber.protocol.ProtocolHandler(jabberClient1_OnAuthError);
            jabberClient1.User = "sa";
            jabberClient1.Server = "gmail.com";
            jabberClient1.Password = "download";
            jabberClient1.Connect();
            jabberClient1.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jabberClient1_OnAuthenticate);
        }

        void jabberClient1_OnAuthenticate(object sender)
        {
            done.Set();
        }

        void jabberClient1_OnAuthError(object sender, System.Xml.XmlElement rp)
        {
            if (rp.Name == "failure")
            {
                Response.Write("Invalid User Name or Password");
            }
        }

        void jabberClient1_OnError(object sender, Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        void jabberClient1_OnDisconnect(object sender)
        {
            Response.Write("Disconnected");
        }

        private void jabberClient1_OnMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.Message msg)
        {
            Response.Write("Message Posted");
            //frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].ReceiveFlag = true;
            //string receivedMsg = msg.From.User + " Says : " + msg.Body + "\n";
            //frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].AppendConversation(receivedMsg);
            //frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].Show();
        }
    }


}
```

so i converted it to vb.net like this

```
Imports System    
Imports System.Collections    
Imports System.Collections.Generic    
Imports System.ComponentModel    
Imports System.Data    
Imports System.Drawing    
Imports System.Text    
Imports jabber.client    
Imports System.Threading    
Imports jabber.protocol.iq    
Imports jabber    
Imports Google.GData.Contacts    
Imports Google.GData.Extensions    
Imports jabber.protocol    

Public Class GtalkIntegration    
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page    
    Shared done As New ManualResetEvent(False)    
    Private WithEvents jabberClient1 As New jabber.client.JabberClient()    

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AddHandler jabberClient1.OnMessage, AddressOf jabberClient1_OnMessage
        AddHandler jabberClient1.OnDisconnect, AddressOf jabberClient1_OnDisconnect
        AddHandler jabberClient1.OnError, AddressOf jabberClient1_OnError
        AddHandler jabberClient1.OnAuthError, AddressOf jabberClient1_OnAuthError
        jabberClient1.User = "sa"
        jabberClient1.Server = "gmail.com"
        jabberClient1.Password = "download"
        jabberClient1.Connect()
        AddHandler jabberClient1.OnAuthenticate, AddressOf jabberClient1_OnAuthenticate
    End Sub

    Private Sub jabberClient1_OnAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object)
        done.[Set]()
    End Sub

    Private Sub jabberClient1_OnAuthError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal rp As System.Xml.XmlElement)
        If rp.Name = "failure" Then
            Response.Write("Invalid User Name or Password")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub jabberClient1_OnError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ex As Exception)
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Sub

    Private Sub jabberClient1_OnDisconnect(ByVal sender As Object)
        Response.Write("Disconnected")
    End Sub

    Private Sub jabberClient1_OnMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal msg As jabber.protocol.client.Message)
        Response.Write("Message Posted")
        'frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].ReceiveFlag = true;
        'string receivedMsg = msg.From.User + " Says : " + msg.Body + "\n";
        'frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].AppendConversation(receivedMsg);
        'frmChat[(int)chatIndex[msg.From.Bare]].Show();
    End Sub
End Class
```

but it is giving me error like

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

please help me out guys thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to reference jabber-net.dll, zlib.net.dll, and netlib.Dns.dll.