# What is the right method for a web chat application in c#

Tags: c#, chat

i'm trying to make a chat application using c# that connects to a web server in order to check if there are messages available.

I've tried that by creating HttpWebRequest to check for messages every second, but i notice that it's not good for the server, imagine if there are thousands of users and each user sends an HttpWebRequest every second, that would be heavy.

I heard something about synchronous connection but i think it also sends the same number of HttpWebRequest, (i'm not sure about this part).

So please does any one know the right method for a chat application?

Comment: Hello, check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226688/web-chat-application-asp-net-jabber-ajax-wcf-comet-reverseajax-issues-faced the guy with the answer got some great tutorial links.

Comment: No one of the answers could work with my case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) might be useful in your case.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

Actually the most typical tutorial using this technology is [web chat](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Remoting.Net 
see this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62813/NET-Remoting-Events-Explained
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12586/Remote-Execution-Using-NET-Remoting